# If Mark's gospel presents Jesus as servant, why does John say he's unworthy to loose his shoes?

Tags: exegesis, life-of-jesus, gospel-of-mark, john-the-baptist

If Mark is the gospel which presents Jesus as servant, why did John the Baptist say in verse 7 that he was mightier than he and that he (John) was unworthy to stoop down and untie his shoes?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  When you have a minute, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on  how this site is [a little different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) than other sites around the web. *This is not a comment on the quality of your question, but rather a standard welcome message.*

Comment: @Jim can you specify which verses you are referring to that present Jesus as servant to clarify your question?

Comment: Just because Jesus took the role of a servant does not mean that others were ranked lower than him.

Comment: What you're asking about is one aspect of Christ's being "meek and humble of heart." On the one hand, He is God; no human being is **worthy** to untie His shoes, or to have anything at all to do with Him. On the other hand, He has humbled Himself to be come not only a servant but a victim for our sins. His passion and death, and His presence in the eucharist are way below His divine dignity, yet He accepted them for our benefit.

Comment: This might be a better question for [Hermeneutics.SE].

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between someone's worth, or nature, and their actions.

Jesus, in himself, is the Most High God* and worthy of our worship, praise and adoration. Nothing can change that. John is quite correct to say that  he is not worthy to untie his shoes.

In his incarnation Jesus *takes on the role* of a servant. It's a job he does, and it doesn't in any way diminish his nature.

You might consider the analogy of Prince William, who fulfilled the role of a (relatively junior) officer in the Royal Air Force. While fulfilling that role he accepted the orders of his senior officers, and interacted with other officers as an equal; despite the fact that in reality he outranked every one of them.

**According to most branches of Christianity*.

Comment: Good answer. Plus one. One further thought, however. I agree with you, to some extent, that Jesus took on the ROLE (key word) of a servant, at least during his brief life as Jesus of Nazareth. By the same token, however, I SUGGEST there was never a time within the Godhead when Jesus was not--in a sense--a servant. For eternity, the Son delighted to do his Father's will, as in the creation of all that is, for example (John 1). Mark's perspective of Christ as God's Servant is well accepted, but that does not mean the other Evangelists did not portray him as a servant, since they had their own

Comment: perspective. If I seem to be splitting hairs, then forgive me. I really think, however, there may be some validity to the concept of the Son being eternally at the disposal of the Father. All three persons of the Trinity are co-equal, to be sure, and each is fully God. The Son, however, was so committed to his Sonship--or to put it differently, he was so committed to his inherent identity within the Godhead as the Son, that in a sense (which I can't expand upon just now) he wasn't taking on a role so much as simply being his inherent self. Let me know what you think. Don

Answer (score 0):

The very fact that the statement of John the Baptist finds place in all the Gospels  ( Mtt 3:11; Mk 1:7; Lk 3:16; Jn 1:27) as well as the Acts (13:25) makes its abundantly clear that the Baptist's words  were  more of a prophesy than of a manifestation of sheer humility. The rituals relating to wearing and taking out of shoes and sandals  were clearly laid down in the Jewish custom, right from the times of Old Testament.  In all its probability, John the  Baptist was referring to Jesus as the `Worthy Groom of Israel.'

For more information, please read:

“Whose Sandal Strap I am Not Worthy to Untie” at 
ourladyofwisdom.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/levirate.pdf